# Can somebody explain Pandas bin precision?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, floating-point

So I have a massive amount of data to be binned, and it seems a little... slow?

I've made a minimal example, which mimics the number of datapoints and calculated bins for a smaller subset:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

np.random.seed(1)


n_samples = 37000
n_bins    = 91000

data = pd.Series(np.random.gamma(1, 1, n_samples))

t1 = time.time()
binned_df = pd.cut(data, bins = n_bins, precision = 100).value_counts()
t2 = time.time()
print("pd.cut speed: {}".format(t2-t1))


summed = np.sum(binned_df)
print("sum: {:.4f}".format(summed))
print("len: {}".format(len(binned_df)))
print(binned_df.head())

plt.hist(data, bins = 100)
plt.show()
```

If I set the precision in `pd.cut()` to 100, the script takes about 1.5 s on my computer, and I get very precise bins, e.g. `(0.209274211931, 0.209375434515]`. However, if I set precision to 1, the same action takes about 9.2 s, so quite a bit slower, and now the bins are only defined as e.g. `(0.2093, 0.2094]`.

But why does a higher precision calculate faster? Am I misunderstanding what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code, it looks like giving `pandas` a precision higher than 19 allows you to leap-frog over a loop that is otherwise going to run (provided your `dtype` isn't either `datetime64` or `timedelta64`; see [Line 326](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/reshape/tile.py#L326)). The relevant code begins [on Line 393 and goes to Line 415](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/reshape/tile.py#L393). Double comments are mine:

```
## This function figures out how far to round the bins after decimal place
def _round_frac(x, precision):
    """
    Round the fractional part of the given number
    """
    if not np.isfinite(x) or x == 0:
        return x
    else:
        frac, whole = np.modf(x)
        if whole == 0:
            digits = -int(np.floor(np.log10(abs(frac)))) - 1 + precision
        else:
            digits = precision
        return np.around(x, digits)

## This function loops through and makes the cuts more and more precise
## sequentially and only stops if either the number of unique levels created
## by the precision are equal to the number of bins or, if that doesn't
## work, just returns the precision you gave it. 

## However, range(100, 20) cannot loop so you jump to the end
def _infer_precision(base_precision, bins):
    """Infer an appropriate precision for _round_frac
    """
    for precision in range(base_precision, 20):
        levels = [_round_frac(b, precision) for b in bins]
        if algos.unique(levels).size == bins.size:
            return precision
    return base_precision # default
```

**Edit: Contrived Example**

Say you have a list `my_list` and it has six elements that you want to split into three bins:

```
test = [1.121, 1.123, 1.131, 1.133, 1.141, 1.143]
```

Clearly you want the split after `1.123` and `1.133`, but say you didn't give `pandas` the bins directly but rather the number of bins (`n_bins = 3`). Pretend `pandas` starts its guesswork with cuts that split the data evenly into 3 (**NOTE**: I don't know if this is how `pandas` picks initial cuts - this is just for example purposes):

```
# To calculate where the bin cuts start
x = (1.143 - 1.121)/3
cut1 = 1.121 + x  # 1.1283
cut2 = 1.121 + (2*x) # 1.1356
bins = [cut1, cut2]
```

But on top of this suppose you suggested `pandas` use precision of 1. Applying this precision to the above cuts gives you `1.1` - which is useless for separating `my_list` because every entry looks like `1.1`. So the package needs to go through and use more and more of the decimal numbers on the estimated cut values until the number of resulting levels matches `n_bins`:

```
# Adapted from infer_precision
for precision in range(1, 4):     
    levels = [_round_frac(b, precision) for b in bins]
    print levels
```

This process only stops when the number of unique levels matches the number of bins, or you get to 20 decimal places. Supplying a precision of 100 allows the package to use 100 places after the decimal to weasel its cut values between more and more precise values in your data.

Comment: So below 20, Pandas will adjust the precision appropriately, but above it'll take the given value, because now it's "precise enough" in any case? Not sure I follow completely.

Comment: @komodovaran_ added some explanation because yes, it wasn't well explained before :)